# Anonymity network like tor, but using the model of torrent

Tags: anonymity, tor, torrent

I am thinking about an anonimity network (just as tor), but using some type of guarantee against mis-usage. For example, which torrent does: there is a tracker, which registers who has given how much how many pieces of a file, and uses this data to help or stop the actual downloader.

I am thinking about the same thing, but not with file pieces, but with network bandwidth.

Thus, you could get for example 1 gigabyte anonimized network traffic - but only if you give 1 giga for other somebody.

Does this, or something such this exist already?

Comment: But if there's a tracker, the anonymity of all users of the network will be compromised once the tracker is compromised, and it's also a single point of failure so not much reliability there (an anonymity network will always have enemies such as frustrated movie studios who are mad because their content is being shared there and will always get DDoS'd).

Comment: @André Of course yes, but first: the trackers can be contacted also through anonimized connections, second: there could be a lot of trackers who maintains eachothers ip addresses. Practically, every client could be also tracker in the same time. But these are already advanced things in my plan, in this simple question I only asked if a torrent-like anonimity network exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[Freenet](https://freenetproject.org/)** is the closest to what you mention as it acts as a fully P2P service sharing between nodes in approx. equal ammounts dependent on your settings.
- **[I2P](https://geti2p.net/en/)** doesn't have the same P2P infrastructure and works purely message-based but can still transfer similar amounts of data just not in the same egalitarian way you mention.

You can find a quick comparison of the two here: https://geti2p.net/en/comparison/freenet

And here you will find a list of other smaller networks a well as the two larger ones I mention above: https://geti2p.net/en/comparison